# iOS Auto Renewable Subscriptions and Receipt Validation Clarifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sandbox, subscription

I was wondering if my approach regarding auto-renewable subscriptions is correct.
I have implemented an auto-renewable subscription in my app, it is the only IAP.
When the user launches the app, it performs receipt validation through Apple's servers. When I receive the response I check the *expires_date_ms* in *latest_receipt_info* to see if the user is subscribed or not. 
When I perform receipt validation I also add the *exclude-old-transactions* tag. I have also added a "Restore previous purchases" function to restore older receipts on the first app launch.
Is my approach correct or I am missing something? Also, do auto-renewable subscriptions auto-renew automatically or do I have to implement the feature by myself?

Thanks in advance for any help.
Regards.

Comment: Your approach sounds more or less fine but of course the implementation detail is what counts. The good news is that Apple takes care of renewing the subscriptions. You can try to do it yourself but then you'd be in *epic* violation of your agreement with Apple..

Comment: Ok, thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-renewable in-app subscriptions do renew automatically, you don't need to do anything for that. You just need to check if a subscriber has an active subscription when using your app. You can also activate the grace period in App Store Connect for your subscription, so your users will have access for additional 16 days if Apple could not renew the subscription. You can read more here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/reducing_involuntary_subscriber_churn